# how to read a file without getAssets in java(android)

Tags: java, android

Does anybody knows how can i read a file without using `getAssets();`? I've pasted the file in my assets folder because I thought it would be possible to use this method. The problem is that I have to get the file inside a non-activity class and it's not practical to pass on the context as a parameter since I call this class +8x in my code.

I usually code in C# and I'm frustrated because every solution i see uses the GetAssets().

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody knows how can i read a file without using getAssets();?

You are not reading a file. You are reading an asset, based on:

> I've pasted the file in my assets folder

Assets are files on your development machine. They are not files on the Android device. They are part of your APK, just like resources. And, yes, you need to use `getAssets()` to be able to access assets.

> The problem is that I have to get the file inside a non-activity class

Set up dependency inversion (Dagger, Koin, etc.) and inject a `Context` into this "non-activity class". In other words, if you do not have access to a `Context` on which to call `getAssets()`, that is an architecture problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: `assets` and `raw` won't be processed; these are still zipped files.

Comment: Thank's @commonsWare that was really helpful.

Comment: In this case, even `getApplicationContext()` might work, as it requires no GUI.